# Do the signs of $p(x_i)$, $0\leq i\leq n+1$, uniquely determine the sign of $p(x_{n+2})$ ($p$ polynomial of degree $n$)

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, polynomials, numerical-methods

For distinct $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$, and for $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists a unique polynomial $p$ of degree $n$ (the Lagrange interpolation polynomial) such that $p(x_i) = y_i$ for all $i=1,2,\dots ,n+1$. So if we have a point $x_{n+2} \in \mathbb{R}$ different from $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_{n+1} \in \mathbb{R}$, then the value of $p(x_{n+2})$ is already determined by $x_1, x_2, \dots , x_{n+1}$ and $y_1, y_2, \dots, y_{n+1}$.

Suppose we have a set $X^+ \subseteq \{ x_1, \dots x_{n+1}\}$ on which we want a $n$-degree polynomial $p$ to be positive, and we want that polynomial to be negative on $X^- = \{ x_1, x_2, \dots , x_{n+1} \} \backslash X ^+$. Then, this gives rise to a collection $\mathcal{P}$ of (Lagrange) polynomials of degree $n$.

**My question**
Does $X^+$ fix the sign of $p(x_{n+2})$, $p\in \mathcal{P}$ (in the sense of $\forall p\in \mathcal{P}: p(x_{n+2}) > 0$ or $\forall p\in \mathcal{P}: p(x_{n+2}) < 0$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $$y_{n+2}=b_1y_1+....+b_ny_n+b_{n+1}y_{n+1},$$ where $b_k=L_k(x_{n+2})$.

Consider the basis cases $y_i=1$ if $i\in X^+$ else $y_i=-1$, and $y_k=0$ for $k\ne i$. Then $y_{n+2}=b_iy_i$. The sign remains constant under small perturbations of the $y_k$, so that there are also instances of admissible values $y_k$ with the same sign of $y_{n+2}$. As conclusion, the sign of $b_iy_i$ has to be constant for all $i=1,2,...,n+1$. This means that once a sign is chosen, the composition of $X^+$ follows. For all but these 2 variants, the claim is wrong, the sign of $y_{n+2}$ is not determined by $X_+$.